# Authentication Error when using mode: no-cors using fetch in React

Tags: reactjs, authentication, cors, fetch-api, harvest

I am building a React app that is pulling different stats from services for our internal developers (commits, tracked hours, etc)..

I am using fetch to grab API data from Harvest, a time tracking app. According to [their docs](http://help.getharvest.com/api/authentication/authentication/http-basic/), you can use basic HTTP authentication. When I use the app Postman, all is well and I can see the response just fine. Initially I used:

```
getHarvest(){
    // Set Harvest Headers
   const harvestHeaders = {
     method: 'GET',
     headers: {
       'Authorization': 'Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=',
       'Content-Type': 'application/json',
       'Accept': 'application/json',
       'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
     }
   };

   fetch('https://factor1.harvestapp.com/projects/', harvestHeaders)
   .then( response => response.json() )
   .then( projects => {

    // Do some stuff


   } )
  }
```

This gives me an error in the console:

> Fetch API cannot load https://myaccount.harvestapp.com/projects/.
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 404. If an opaque response
>   serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the
>   resource with CORS disabled.

So with that feedback I changed the function to look like this:

```
getHarvest(){
    // Set Harvest Headers
   const harvestHeaders = {
     method: 'GET',
     mode: 'no-cors',
     headers: {
       'Authorization': 'Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=',
       'Content-Type': 'application/json',
       'Accept': 'application/json',
       'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
     }
   };

   fetch('https://factor1.harvestapp.com/projects/', harvestHeaders)
   .then( response => response.json() )
   .then( projects => {

    // do stuff


   } )
  }
```

But that results in an Authentication error:

`GET https://myaccount.harvestapp.com/projects/ 401 (Unauthorized)`

I'm not sure how I can get the response correctly. Am I doing something wrong? It seems odd to me that using the app Postman works but this doesn't. Thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn’t seem like the Harvest API is meant to be used with XHR or Fetch from Web applications.

At least [their docs](http://help.getharvest.com/api/) don’t mention anything about using their API from XHR or Fetch, nor do those docs mention anything about `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` nor CORS in general.

Instead the docs give examples of using the API with `curl` and with the Postman REST Client.

And trying examples in the docs like below, the response has no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/xml' -H 'Accept: application/xml' \
  -u "user@example.com:password" https://example.harvestapp.com/account/who_am_i
```

So it seems like the answer is: You can’t access the Harvest API with XHR/Fetch from a Web app.

It works in Postman because Postman is not bound by the same-origin policy  browsers enforce to prevent Web apps running in a browser from making cross-origin requests unless the site/endpoint the request is made to has opted in to using CORS (which it seems Harvest hasn’t opted into).